# Confusion about enumitem and expansion in labels

Tags: expansion, enumitem

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I'm trying to obtain it using this code:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{entry}
\setcounter{entry}{1000}

\newcommand{\xlistformat}[1]{\theentry.~(#1)} % This is the interesting part

\newlist{xlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[xlist]{
  label = {\xlistformat{\alph*}},
  leftmargin = *,
  align = left
}

\begin{xlist}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut 
      purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

      Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
      consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{xlist}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work. I get this instead:
[image]

I can make it work by changing

```
\newcommand{\xlistformat}[1]{\theentry.~(#1)}
```

to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xlistformat}[1]{\number\c@entry.~(#1)}
\makeatother
```

but this has many other problems.

I'm not sure what I need to change to get this working. I've tried using the `format` key instead of the `label`, but that has given essentially the same result. My guess is that something's going wrong with the expansion of `\theentry`, but my experiments in that direction have borne no fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `widest` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, fmtcount, siunitx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{entry}
\setcounter{entry}{100000000}

\newlength\entrylg\settowidth{\entrylg}{\theentry.}

\newcommand{\xlistformat}[1]{\theentry.~(#1)} % This is the interesting part

\newlist{xlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[xlist]{
label = {\xlistformat{\alph*}},
widest = \makebox[\entrylg]{}, 
align=left,
leftmargin =*, 
}

\begin{xlist}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
      purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

      Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
      consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

\setcounter{xlisti}{12}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
      purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

      Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
      consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

\end{xlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `widest` doesn't work if the definition of `\xlistformat` (or, for that matter, `\theentry` or the entry counter itself) changes. It also doesn't explain why simply replacing `\theentry` with `\number\c@entry` fixes the problem.

Comment: @Derek: I've modified the code to take your observation into account, adding a new length (`\entrylg`), which is read by `widest`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I set the value of `entry` to 1 (for example) instead of 100000000, there's a huge gap between the right edge of "(a)" and the start of the item text. Not sure why. I appreciate the help, though!

Comment: @Derek: I've changed the definition of `widest`, and it seems to work.

Comment: Although I tweaked this some to get the final effect I wanted, it had a lot of good ideas. Thanks.